# Locked out of ssh from server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I was logged into my AWS EC2 server via ssh. I ran `iptables -P INPUT DROP` to check something and I forgot to enable port 22 so that I could keep my ssh connection.

Is there something I can do to regain back the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [AWS System Manager Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html) if your server has the AWS SSM agent installed on the EC2 server and the correct IAM permissions, etc.

Or you could use [AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) to run a single command to fix the iptables, if you have the AWS SSM agent installed on the EC2 server.

Otherwise, you didn't save the iptables rules, so they should reset back to the previous settings if you reboot the server.

Comment: Your third suggestion, was the one that helped. Thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. Please close off-topic questions. Please don't encourage them.